# Can't copy files to inetpub/wwwroot in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security, iis

I'm trying to copy some files to wwwroot in windows 7 but can't do it. It used to work but know it just shows this

[image]

and when I click on continue it doesn't do anything.

Also a lot of things give:

[image: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service" error].

For example trying to open command prompt as administrator or IIS manager.

It used to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check first few things -
1)Your only user 
2)Your Administrator of this systems.

Scenario No- 1
Then you can,t change a folder permission

Scenario No- 2
Your are Administrator

Step -1 
Go to physical path - 
Ex-C:\

Right Click on inetpub folder

Click on properties > security > Advanced >Edit >Select local user > Click on Full controller and user can modify files sections > Apply > ok

Step 2: - Copy the same folder and check folder is successfully coping.